# Showing Toast above keyboard in Obejctive c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, mbprogresshud

I have write a function thats displays the toast on `UIVIewController`. The toast function is given below

```
-(void)showToast:(NSString*)string
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText = string;
    hud.margin = 10.f;
    hud.yOffset = 150.f;
    hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    hud.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:2];
}
```

Now the issue is that my toast message hides behind the keyboard. Can anyone tell me how to show toast above the height of keyboard?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161590/how-to-add-a-uiview-over-the-keyboard-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question with answer is here: 
[Position MBProgressHUD at the Bottom/Top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728060/position-mbprogresshud-at-the-bottom-top-of-the-screen)

In short, use the `yOffset` property of the `MBProgressHUD` to change its Y position.